# How to create a space instead of a multiplication sign in an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, math-operators

In LaTeX, I want to create the following equation:

```
    \begin{equation}
    x(t) = A1 sin(2 \pi f_1 t) + A2 sin(2 \pi f_2 t) 
    \end{equation}
```

I don't want to show the multiplication sign. But is there a way to have a space where the multiplication sign would be? So for example between A1 and sin() ?

Also, how can I change the letter size of my equation?

Thanks for help!

Comment: In math mode, you can use `\,` for thin space, `\:` for medium space, `\;` for thick space, `\!` for thin negative space.  Also, `~` for full space.  See LaTeX manual (Lamport, p. 52), for example.

Comment: You should be using `\sin`. In the general case LaTeX will insert appropriate spacing for you, you shouldn't really *need* to do anything, but I suppose if you have a specific aesthetic, @StevenB.Segletes's suggestions above should do

Comment: If `A1` doesn't denote `A times 1` then normally it would be marked as A_1 for example, with a subscript. and use `\sin` then spacing should be correct without adding any extra spaces.

Comment: What is the concern about the font size of your math letters?

Answer (score 4):

As Au101 pointed out, use `\sin`.  Also, you presumably want a subscript on the A's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
     \begin{equation}
     x(t) = A_1 \sin(2 \pi f_1 t) + A_2 \sin(2 \pi f_2 t) 
     \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]